# ffmpeg-php with fixed width and height and without stretch or squish

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hi there I googled for hours but no success to solve...

This code works for me

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $SourcePath -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f wemp -vf scale=500x400,setdar=16:9  $uploadpath1 2>&1");
```

but the output video will be stretch or squish...I don't want it...what can I to do?[image]

Comment: Why are you doubling the size in the first place?  You can't simply increase image quality.  This doesn't do anything other than increase the file size and decrease the overall quality.

Comment: The quality is not my business...I want to define an standard size frame for my all videos...and each inputed video change to this size frame but without stretch or squish

Comment: Are all your videos the same aspect ratio to begin with?  If they are not, you will need to do cropping then?  If they are, is there a reason you can't scale at playback?  Display size is independent of actual pixels in the video.

Comment: What is the reason for forcing videos into this frame size? If you want fixed dimensions you should only scale the video down to a fixed width, not both, and add the black borders in your application.

Comment: I want to do it as youtube...all youtube videos are same width and height to show...

Comment: Have you looked at this answer to a similar question? http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/how-do-i-change-frame-size-preserving-width-using-ffmpeg?rq=1